# Dividing each row of a dataframe by the sum of squared variables

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a clean way to divide each row of a dataframe by the sum of squared variables, in a time series database ---- where the events are the rows and the columns are the variables ---. At the moment, my method is the following

```
for(i in 1:nrow(base)){
     base[i,] <- base[i,]/(as.numeric(t(c(base[i,]))) %*% as.numeric(t(c(base[i,]))))
  }
```

In order to use the `%*%` operator the only way I found is the one shown above which uses the `as.numeric %>% t %>% c` mechanism, which it doesn't seems clean.

For the sake of a reproducible example:

```
base <-structure(list(Var1 = c(920, 734, 1001, 1033, 752, 837, 734, 
817), Var2 = c(4861, 4966, 4855, 3835, 4782, 5348, 4648, 4595
), Var3 = c(5011, 4618, 2718, 4344, 4872, 5076, 4678, 4563), 
    Var4 = c(4785, 4610, 4697, 4149, 4693, 4866, 4517, 3271), 
    Var5 = c(5101, 4220, 4444, 4301, 965, 4557, 3524, 4201), 
    Var6 = c(5059, 4048, 4217, 4397, 3711, 4032, 5478, 4051), 
    Var7 = c(2134, 1766, 1640, 1837, 1662, 1711, 1838, 1625)), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Var6", "Var7"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1b8ec38>)
```

Comment: Do you mean to have an assignment in that for loop?

Comment: I've forgotten to add the assignment. The code is now correct

Comment: *"I'm not sure if standardization is the correct word."* I would tend to concur. Usually in statistics standardising variables refers to Z score scaling, which is realised in R through `scale`. Can you edit your post to include an explanation on what you mean by "standardization"?

Comment: What do you mean by standardize? I guess you're dividing by the sum of squared row values.

Comment: just for the sake of completeness... `t(apply(mtcars,1, function(x) x/(x %*% x)))` is closer to your original ... though Im not sure it's any clearer reallly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also question what you mean by standardize, however here is a simpler way to accomplish what you're doing in the for loop:

```
sweep(base, 1, rowSums(base^2), `/`)
```

Comment: It is also 20 times faster.